# POSTGRES Group by / Inner Join

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, group-by

I am having problems writing a query to summarize the number trips from a OD matrix table.  I am still new to using databases other than MS Access, so please forgive my inexperience. SMGZ is the table with the number of zones and matrix_od is the matrix table with all the OD pairs(4109*4109) from zone to zone with the total number of trip types. I am not sure this is the best way to write this query.  SO what i need to do is summarize 4 types of trips(LHDT,MHDT,HHDT,HDT_Tota) by the OD. Help is much appreciated.

```
SELECT 
   smgz.smg_zone AS "O_ID",
   smgz.x AS "O_X",
   smgz.y AS "O_Y",
   smgz1.smg_zone AS "D_ID",
   smgz1.x AS "D_X",
   smgz1.y AS "D_Y",
   SUM(matrix_od."LHDT") AS "LHDT_Tot", 
   SUM(matrix_od."MHDT") AS "MHDT_Tot", 
   SUM(matrix_od."HHDT") AS "HHDT_Tot", 
   SUM(matrix_od."TOT_HDT") AS "HDT_Tot"
FROM 
   public.smgz, 
   public.matrix_od, 
   public.smgz smgz1
GROUP BY
  "O_ID","O_X","O_Y","D_ID","D_X","D_Y"
INNER JOIN 
  smgz on matrix_od.O_ID = smgz.ID
INNER JOIN 
  smgz1 on matrix_od.D_ID = smgz1.ID;


 ERROR:  syntax error at or near "INNER"
 LINE 18: INNER JOIN 
          ^

********** Error **********

 ERROR: syntax error at or near "INNER"
 SQL state: 42601
 Character: 414
```

Comment: The joins should be before the `GROUP BY`. Also, you are performing quite the cartesian products there

Comment: You are mixing implicit join syntax and explicit `JOIN` operator. Don't do that.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in comments the two main errors are that the `group by` clause is in the wrong place, it should be after the joins, and that you are mixing implicit joins (multiple tables in the from clause) with explicit joins (using the join keyword). The fix is to change this part:

```
FROM 
   public.smgz, 
   public.matrix_od, 
   public.smgz smgz1
GROUP BY
  "O_ID","O_X","O_Y","D_ID","D_X","D_Y"
INNER JOIN 
  smgz on matrix_od.O_ID = smgz.ID
INNER JOIN 
  smgz1 on matrix_od.D_ID = smgz1.ID;
```

to this:

```
FROM 
  public.matrix_od
INNER JOIN 
  public.smgz on matrix_od.O_ID = smgz.ID
INNER JOIN 
  public.smgz smgz1 on matrix_od.D_ID = smgz1.ID
GROUP BY
  "O_ID","O_X","O_Y","D_ID","D_X","D_Y";
```

Comment: That gives me a error smgz1 is just an alias to smgz ERROR:         ERROR:relation      "smgz1" does not exist
    LINE 17:   smgz1 on matrix_od."D_ID" = smgz1."id"
                     ^
    ********** Error **********

    ERROR: relation "smgz1" does not exist
    SQL state: 42P01
    Character: 394

Comment: @aconti74 My bad, forgot to add the alias in the join. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

That did the trick! Thank you @a_horse_with_no_name & @Lamak.

```
 SELECT
  smgz.smg_zone AS "O_ID",
  smgz.x AS "O_X",
  smgz.y AS "O_Y",
  smgz1.smg_zone AS "O_ID",
  smgz1.x AS "D_X",
  smgz1.y AS "D_Y",     
  SUM(matrix_od."LHDT") AS "LHDT_Tot", 
  SUM(matrix_od."MHDT") AS "MHDT_Tot", 
  SUM(matrix_od."HHDT") AS "HHDT_Tot", 
  SUM(matrix_od."TOT_HDT") AS "HDT_Tot"
FROM 
  public.matrix_od 
INNER JOIN 
  smgz on matrix_od."O_ID" = smgz."id"
INNER JOIN 
  public.smgz smgz1 on matrix_od."D_ID" = smgz1."id"
GROUP BY
  smgz.smg_zone,smgz.x,smgz.y,smgz1.smg_zone,smgz1.x,smgz1.y;
```